# How to catch/handle the window form's hidden/showed events?

Tags: winforms

In my application I call  App.Current.MainWindow.Show()/App.Current.MainWindow.Hide() to show/hide my application but I don't know how to catch the event when the form is hidden/showed. Please help if you know how to!

Comment: Question - if you're CALLING the Hide and Show in your code, why do you need to capture the events?  You already KNOW when it's happening.  If you want to run some code inside the form after hiding and closing it, expose the code as a public function, and call the function after showing and hiding the form...

Comment: @David Stratton: Your suggestion is the right solution I'm looking for. It was such a dumbing day for me when I asked about this! Thank you David! 
ps. I wish to choose your comment to be marked as answer but it's impossible.

Comment: I added the comment to my answer below so you could accept it if you choose.  Glad I could help!  (And it's not dumb.  We all miss the obvious sometimes.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your tags is WPF and the other is WinForms...   I'm better with WinForms, so I'll answer for that tag.

The Form.Shown event documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx) with sample code...

There is no corresponding Form.Hidden event.  The best you can do is choose from [Form.Closing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) or [Form.Closed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed.aspx) or one of the other events.

**Added from my comment above**

Question - if you're CALLING the Hide and Show in your code, why do you need to capture the events? You already KNOW when it's happening. If you want to run some code inside the form after hiding and closing it, expose the code as a public function, and call the function after showing and hiding the form...